# Automatically generate the input

Tags: javascript, html

I have following select options and a text box to get the ID. I want to know that how can I get the text box output based on the input from two select options.
 eg: If the user selects "Single Needle" and "Mator" then the ID should be "SNM1".

Option 1

```
<select class="form-control" name="mtype" id="mtype">
    <option> Single Needle </option>
    <option> Double Needle </option>
     <option> OverLock </option>
 </select>
```

Option 2

```
<select class="form-control"  name="mmodel" id="mmodel">
    <option>Mator </option>
    <option>Sling </option>
    </select>
```

Text Box

```
<label>Machine ID</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="mid" id="mid">
```

Comment: You can use an `onchange` event on your `select` items and check the values to set `mid` accordingly. But how are you getting `SNM1`, specifically the `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var mtype = document.querySelector('#mtype');
var mmodel = document.querySelector('#mmodel');

mtype.onchange = change;
mmodel.onchange = change;

function change() {
  if (mtype.value != '' && mmodel.value != '') {
    document.querySelector('#mid').value = mtype.value + mmodel.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Type</div>
<select class="form-control" name="mtype" id="mtype">
  <option value="">Pick Type</option>
  <option value="SN">Single Needle</option>
  <option value="DN">Double Needle</option>
  <option value="OL">OverLock</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div>Model</div>
<select class="form-control" name="mmodel" id="mmodel">
  <option value="">Pick Model</option>
  <option value="M1">Mator </option>
  <option value="M2">Sling</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div>
  <label>Machine ID</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="mid" id="mid" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Code</title>
 <script>
  function fnValue()
   {
   var text1=document.getElementById('mtype').value
   var text2=document.getElementById('mmodel').value
   document.getElementById('mid').value=text1+text2;
   }
   window.onload=fnValue;
 </script>
<body>
 <select class="form-control" name="mtype" id="mtype" onchange="fnValue()">
  <option value="SN"> Single Needle </option>
  <option value="DN"> Double Needle </option>
  <option value="OL"> OverLock </option>
 </select>
 <select class="form-control"  name="mmodel" id="mmodel" onchange="fnValue()">
  <option value="M1">Mator </option>
  <option value="M2">Sling </option>
 </select>
 <label>Machine ID</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="mid" id="mid">
 </body>
 </head>
 </html>
```